How do I add 1 second of silence before every track in Audacity?
I have an Audacity project with 6 different tracks and I want to add 1 second of silence before every track. The use case is I am trying to record a vocal track, but I need a moment after hitting record to prepare myself.

One option is to Select All (Ctrl+A) then drag your audio tracks to the right by 1 second on the timeline. When using Select All, every track will get moved at the same time.

